# Make and create Live USB Linux for Mac? How?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, unix, bootable-disk

I'm wanting to create a live usb linux so I can easily access it everytime when I need it without taking up any space.
But with other sources, they say to rEFInd and I did so, however when restarting and accessing the boot menu, nothing happens.

I am running Yosemite 10.10 on a Macbook Pro - I still have rEFInd on my mac.

I already have .iso version of the linux and UnetBootin

**Any way how to make a live usb linux on a Yosemite Macbook Pro?**

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the desired .img file
2. Open a Terminal (under Utilities)

   - If you have and .iso file, you could convert to .img with the command `hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/source.iso`.
3. Run `diskutil list` to get the current list of devices
4. Insert your flash media
5. Run `diskutil list` again and determine the device node assigned to your flash media (e.g. `/dev/disk2`)
6. Run `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN`
7. Execute `sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/diskN bs=1m`
8. Run `diskutil eject /dev/diskN` and remove your flash media when the command completes

Restart your Mac and press <kbd>⌥</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd> key while the Mac is restarting to choose the USB stick.

Comment: there's only a .iso file - I'm trying to get Kali Linux running from a usb **|** Will running terminal do the same to .iso instead of .img? _if this works i'll wont need rEFInd from now on_

Comment: Updated my previous answer.

Comment: Ok i'll try tonight when I get back home/to boarding house. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: sorry, it turned out I was hesitant and the downloads page on Kali **did** provide an image file, but when I downloaded it, it downloaded something like "kaillinux.img.xz" what was the .xz ? I renamed it to .img then put it through terminal and after giving it permission, it "did" nothing. typing anything gives it no response.

Comment: Must be a tar.xz. To uncompress use `tar xvfJ kaillinux.img.xz`.

Comment: I forget to mention, there was two versions of the downloads, ARMEL and ARMHF - which versions do I use?

Comment: tar xvfj doesn't work on .img.xz - it said `tar xvfj /Users/__________/Downloads/kali-linux-1.0.9a-armel.img.xz 
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.` this is the same with armhf

Comment: Images are for ARM and you can't use it. You have to use `Kali Linux 64 bit ISO`. Anyway, you could convert the iso downloaded to img as I told you in the answer, with `hdiutil` command.

Comment: `hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/Downloads/kali-linux-1.0.9a-amd64.img ~/Downloads/kali-linux-1.0.9a-amd64.iso ` response: `hdiutil: convert failed - image not recognized`

Comment: Maybe your file is corrupted. [Kali docs](http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-dual-boot-on-mac-hardware) says that you must only copy the iso file to your usb drive. Did you tried it?

Comment: I've moved the .iso file to a 32Gb journaled mac usb - tried the hdutil still came up with image not recognized - how about I will look up online on how to .iso to .img

Comment: Sometimes there are tar.xz files but this is not a tar only an xz. To unzip an xz file: `unxz ~/Downloads/kali-linux-1.0.9a-armel.img.xz ~/Downloads/kali-linux-1.0.9a-armel.img` or you could use: `xz -dc ~/Downloads/kali-linux-1.0.9a-armel.img.xz ~/Downloads/kali-linux-1.0.9a-armel.img`